# Improving an algorithm involving two pairs of sums

Tags: time-complexity

Suppose $l=[a[0],a[1],a[2],,a[n]]$ be a list of  numbers. I need to  calculate $$ \sum a[j]a[k]a[j']a[k'] $$
such that $j+k=j'+k'$ .Obviously we can implement it in $O(n^4)$ time complexity by the exhaustive search method.Can we do it better?It is pertinent to mention the number of tuples satisfying $j+k=j'+k'$ are approximately $n^3.$Any help/hints are highly appreciated

Comment: What's the motivation for this task, or the contest where you encountered it?  Can you credit the original source.

Comment: it is just a combinatorial problem for finding the number of tuples from the set $\{ 0,1,2,,n\}$ such that$j+k=j'+k'.$ Since combinatorics is a good playground for algorithms ,I was just wondering whether we can do it in some faster way

Comment: Your edit changed the question (in a way that invalidated an existing answer) and made the formatting worse.  Please decide what question you want to ask, and proof-read the question.  Enumerating all such tuples is a trivial matter of programming.  Please spend some time trying it, and show what you've come up with in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trivial to do in $O(n^3)$ time, by enumerating all $O(n^3)$ tuples $(j,k,j',k')$ such that $j+k=j'+k'$, computing the appropriate product, and summing those products.  I'll let you discover how to enumerate those tuples.  I am confident you can figure that out: if you spend a little time thinking about it and/or working through some small examples with $n=1$, $n=2$, $n=3$ by hand, I'm sure you'll be able to come up with an algorithm.

You can compute this sum in $O(n^2)$ time using the following identity:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum a[j]a[k]a[j']a[k']
&= \sum_s \sum_{j,j'} a[j] a[s-j] a[j'] a[s-j']\\
&= \sum_s \left(\sum_j a[j] a[s-j] \right)^2.
\end{align*}$$

where $s$ ranges over $0,1,2,\dots,2n$ and $j,j'$ range over $0 \le j \le \min(n,s)$ and $0 \le j' \le \min(n,s)$.

Comment: Don't we have to run 4 loops for j,k,j',k'?sorry if this is a silly question

Comment: Oh this is beautiful!I got it now!Thank you for your clever approach